# String was not in a correct format when parsed with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, parsing

When I try to parse this string into a date:

```
1.05.2016
```

With this code:

```
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(),
              "dd.m.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

An error occurs:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at _09.Holidays_Between_Two_Dates.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\martin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Methods. Debugging - Troubleshooting Code\09. Holidays Between Two Dates\09. Holidays Between Two Dates.cs:line 15
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `"d.MM.yyyy"`as format

Comment: [How do I format a DateTime in a different format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650681/how-do-i-format-a-datetime-in-a-different-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"M" stands for months and "m" stands for minutes. Make sure that you use correct one:

```
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(),
             "dd.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct the format because the input datetime format and provided format must match

for your input `1.05.2016` you can use

```
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(),
              "d.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but date will be not always single digit, so better to use double digit `01.05.2016` and

```
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(),
              "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Why must he change the input?

Comment: for safety, because not all the time date will be single digit, but it can be omit

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Using "d.MM.yyyy" as format,will correctly parse `11.05.2016` for example.It does not limit the day to 1 digit

Comment: Pikoh is right. Unpadded month number (`d`)  and padded one (`dd`) will only make a difference when **formatting**, not when parsing. Format used might as well be `"d.M.yyyy"` and it will still work - only the year must remain as `yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double-check your input from the Console.Readline()? Perhaps it contains the carriage return or some other illegal characters? I ran the following in LinqPad:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1.05.2016","d.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();
```

And it returned "01/05/2016 00:00:00".