# Convert DateTime to dd-MM-yyyy format in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am creating a web app in which I am fetching a date from textbox into the webservice

current date format of my date is like this `10-October-2016` but I want to convert it into `10-10-2016`

I want to convert it in webservice itself

can anyone help me out

Comment: @SomeUser i cant see any relevent thing on that answer

Comment: i think this is work for you dateVariable.ToString("DD-MM-YYYY").

Comment: @Div: that answer does not cover the parsing part of the question.

Comment: Varibale that hold date 10-October -2016  is type of ?

Comment: @Richard, Yes you are right, but there are numbers of question which can able to solve this, look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649639/how-to-convert-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Div that's the same Q you linked to earlier (and it still doesn't handling parsing into a `DateTime` to allow formatting).

Comment: @Richard, Oops..sorry for that! look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050102/convert-datetime-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650681/how-do-i-format-a-datetime-in-a-different-format

Comment: That's more more like a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert using `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
string dt = "10-October-2016";
string date = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd-MMMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: its working sir thank you

Comment: great, you are most welcome