# C# datetime precision

Tags: c#, datetime, precision

Let's imagine that we have one variable in C#

```
System.DateTime dt = 07/11/2018 16:10:10.2345
```

is it possible to change any property in dt or cast it to anything else so every time I use it, serialize it or make it to string to give

```
07/11/2018 16:10:10.23450000
```

thanks

Comment: You'd need to create a wrapper type with your specific `ToString()` needs. Something like `MyDateTime`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a DateTime in a different format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35650681/1260204)

Comment: In the application we develop, in some modules dates are shown as 01/01/2000 12:12:12.12345678Z but in the old modules as 01/01/2000 12:12:12.123. My boss asked me if we can find any easy way to convert somehow the "old dates" so when we show them to be similar as in the new modules. it seems that it is not possible to make C# show the zeros in the end, unless you explicitly format them.

Comment: Your first line of code is not C#.  There is no literal DateTime format in the language.  If you want to change how it gets parsed from a string or serialized out to a string, you could implement an `IFormatProvider` and use that in your parsing/ToString calls.  As everyone else has said, DateTimes are structures containing information, they don't have a "native" string representation.

Comment: Thanks for providing some additional context. `In the application we develop` <= can you share 1) what type of application this is (that is, what is rendering the dates)? Any (sample) code you have for presenting the dates where you would like that date to be displayed differently (by adding precision).

Answer (score 6):

`DateTime` does not *have* a format. You specify one when you *display* it. That is where you should force the format.  The default format when a `DateTime` is displayed is defined by the culture of the machine; there is no setting on `DateTime` to set a different default format.

Note also that you can't inherit from `DateTime` to override the default format; you'd have to *wrap* it in a new class, which may be more trouble than it's worth.